# Can not upgrade Aurora RDS Postgres version from 12 to 13

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I am trying to upgrade Aurora RDS Postgres cluster db.r5.xlarge from version 12.7 to 13.3.
I choose Engine version 13.3, default DB cluster parameter group and DB parameter group default.aurora-postgresql13 and choose 'Apply immediately'.

Received error message:

> We're sorry, your request to modify DB cluster clone-cluster has failed.
> Cannot modify engine version because instance clone-cluster is running on an old configuration.
> Apply any pending maintenance actions on the instance before proceeding with the upgrade

There are no any pending maintenance actions showing in AWS RDS console and I have no idea what configuration they mean.

We are on a free basic support plan no so we cannot get help from AWS. Can anyone please suggest if there's a way to upgrade the whole cluster at once?

Comment: Dump/restore? Such are the pains of hosted databases.

Comment: there are about 60 databases, so gonna be a pain in the rear

Comment: I am having this same issue and also have quite a few databases. I also tried using the command line option to no avail `aws rds modify-db-cluster --db-cluster-identifier mydbcluster --engine-version 13.3 --allow-major-version-upgrade --apply-immediately`

Comment: I found this chart useful, although I don't think it affects your upgrade path.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.PostgreSQL.html#USER_UpgradeDBInstance.PostgreSQL.MajorVersion

Answer (score 20):

I had this issue and contacted AWS support. They said it is a known issue for (some, or all) db.t3 instance types. In my case I was using db.t3.medium.

So the workaround is as follows:

- Change instance type on the cluster to r5.xlarge or db.r6g.large.
- Upgrade to PostgreSQL 13.3
- Change instance type back to db.t3.medium.

Comment: For me it wouldn't work regardless of the instance type. I have some t3.mediums and some r5.large but when I changed the instance type it allowed me to upgrade. t3.medium -> r5.large and r5.large to r5.xlarge. Then change the instance types back after the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for this post! I had the same issue and contacted AWS support and received the same suggestion (upgrade to r6.large). For me, I was testing with a db.r4.large upgrading postgres 10 > 11 > 12 worked, 12 > 13 didn't. I changed the instance type to a db.r5.large and then was able to upgrade to 13. But I upgraded our other instances to db.r5.large first, then upgraded postgres 10 > 11 > 12, and 12 > 13 didn't work. So we will hold off until they fix it, as we have about 24 we'd have to manually change instance class for, then upgrade, then change back.

Comment: Worked for me as well! Thanks for that 

Comment: I had the same error when upgrading from version 12 to 13 on a db.t3.medium.  But in my case, there _was_ a maintenance action listed  (something about a OS version update).  After I applied that action I was able to update to 13.   So maybe AWS has fixed the issue?  Or maybe my cluster had an issue unrelated to yours.

Comment: The more I use RDS, the more I dislike it. Thank you for this, saved my evening.

Comment: Wow IDK how I would have figured that out. Thanks!

Comment: I also encountered same error as @WesleySmith, upgrading from 12.8 to 13.4 -- reader was listed as "New Operating System update is available".  `describe-pending-maintenance-actions` RDS CLI will report this.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the other great answers, another possible reason for "old configuration" errors is attempting to upgrade from an old minor version.

I was trying to upgrade from Postgres 12.6 directly to 13.3, which is not supported.
Instead, I had to upgrade to 12.7 first and then upgrade to 13.3.

It's written in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.PostgreSQL.html), but I didn't notice the minor version requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Hit the same issue with upgrade to a major version and here's the undocumented solution I found:

- Select an instance from the cluster, and in the actions menu you should see `Upgrade Now`.
- Do this for each instance that is part of the cluster.
- Modify the cluster and you should be able to upgrade to any available 13.x version.

Even though it is shown as the same version as the Cluster, the `Upgrade now` action will run configuration update on the instance itself putting it in maintenance and rebooting it.

Answer (score 0):

This is [not correctly documented](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.DBInstance.Modifying.html) at the moment, but it is possible to check and resolve (for those of us automating the upgrade process.) The CLI `aws rds describe-pending-maintenance-actions` *sometimes* reports the status.  If you know ARNs, you can filter on them, or if just a name, this seems to work:

```
aws rds describe-pending-maintenance-actions --query 'PendingMaintenanceActions[?contains(ResourceIdentifier, `test`)`
```

The maintenance can be applied programmatically using [apply-pending-maintenance-action](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/rds/apply-pending-maintenance-action.html).

### However...

This message also appears to occur when something about the upgrade path is invalid.  In my case, I believe the case is as follows:

- Source is 9.6.19 Aurora PostgreSQL
- Target is 10.18.  This fails.
- Set target to 10.14 and upgrade occurs

In short, the UI, and other information about what versions of what are compatible is incomplete.  I have reported this to AWS and they mostly shrugged, telling me to look at the doc.  Pffft.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me. In rds, select the server highlighted in the error message, go to "Configuration" and make sure that the "Recommendations" area is empty, otherwise, "Apply Now" the recommendation/s. Once all completed, "Modify" from the Global/Regional Cluster and try to upgrade again.
[image]